# how to direct to correct html page when using Restcontroller

Tags: spring-mvc

How do I render view to the page that I want after directing my URL to restController after submitting form? I understand that it is not a good practice to render view in RESTController.

Any advice?

Comment: What you have tried? show some code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47524885/how-to-pass-values-from-controller-in-one-folder-to-restcontroller-in-another-fo

Comment: I do not know how to link the two controllers together to make my application work

Comment: `@RestController` and `@Controller` both are different in spring. Read Spring documentation.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you would provide me with more information. I have read through many document including spring documentation, but have not figured out how i can link to rest controller using controller.

Comment: If you submit some form and receive some data from controller, then you would not use `RestController` as this is use for providing rest-api. `Controller` would be enough but I didn't know why this wired requirement you need.

Comment: I am trying to build API and using RESTController is part of my requirement

Comment: If you are building a rest-api, then why you need to render a view from your `RestController`. Rest-Api only serves you by providing your required data from a specific end-point, you get the data and render/Push the data into view. Isn't it?

Comment: This is the part that I am confuse, I do not know how I can push the data into view.

Comment: `model.addAttribute("object",object);` or `modelAndView.addObject("object",object)`